# Queue (people waiting) management system data

Tags: data-request, api

I was looking for the data from electronic ticket systems (like those in hospitals or government units) and unable to find any.

It'd be cool to have raw data, namely, the time when ticket T was issued and time when it was called for. That'd tell a lot about workloads of the unit and its bottlenecks. Maybe workloads are unbalanced and visitors should be recommended to come in certain hours, when there're no long lines.

Relevant APIs would be great as well.

Anyone saw data like this or similar?

[image: Queue system CC-BY-SA commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Queue_Management_System_Display_Screen_at_Emirates.jpg]